# Numpy use all rows in multidimensional integer indexing

Tags: python, numpy

I have a multidimensional array in numpy:

```
a=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

   array([[1, 2, 3],
          [4, 5, 6],
          [7, 8, 9]])
```

Let's say I want to access the elements `2,5, and 9`.
I know that I can use integer indexing to do it like:

```
a[np.arange(3),np.array([1,1,2])]
>>>array([2, 5, 9])
```

But is there a way to select every row without the use of `np.arrange`?
I already know that `a[:,np.array([1,1,2])]` is not working since it returns

```
array([[2, 2, 3],
       [5, 5, 6],
       [8, 8, 9]])
```

There is probably some easy way, but I missed it in the documentation.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, but you can use `a[range(3),[1,1,2]]` instead of `a[np.arange(3),np.array([1,1,2])]` for the same result

Comment: I think the use of `np.arange` is actually idiomatic in this case. However, you can also use `np.take_along_axis`: `np.take_along_axis(a, np.array([1,1,2])[:,None], 1).squeeze()`. I would not recommend it in this case, but it comes in handy in other applications.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem It still works, so you might as well make an answer

Comment: What is wrong with the `arange`?  That was the only way, until the `take_along` was added.  If you understand why it works, and is required, you can extend the idea to related cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.take_along_axis`

```
np.take_along_axis(a, np.array([1,1,2])[:,None], 1).squeeze() # correction by @hilberts_drinking_problem

Out: array([2, 5, 9])
```

Comment: It's not really a result requested. We need to get `array([2, 5, 9])` without using `range` or `arange`

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem you're right I did the wrong axis to take along.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a solution for easier access to all items in dim, but if you want to select specific items in the array, you can pass a list into dim to say NumPy iterate over the next dim if it is also a list.

e.g.

```
def some(i):
     return [i, i+1]

a[some(0), [1, 2]]
```

returns `array([2, 6])`